# Requiring 3D Touch only devices - iOS App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, 3dtouch

Is there a way to require the 3dtouch feature for a device to be able to download your app on the App Store?

Comment: You should submit an enhancement request bug report to Apple for this device capability requirement.

Comment: has someone how already submitted this

Comment: Duplicate enhancement requests are reported to raise the visibility of that request.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this. You would need to add `3d-touch`, or something of that nature, to your `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your `Info.plist`. These are the capability keys, according to Apple's [Device Compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) article:

```
accelerometer
armv6
armv7
auto-focus-camera
bluetooth-le
camera-flash
front-facing-camera
gamekit
gps
gyroscope
healthkit
location-services
magnetometer
metal
microphone
opengles-1
opengles-2
opengles-3
peer-peer
sms
still-camera
telephony
video-camera
wifi
```

As of now, there isn't a key that would allow you to require 3D Touch. Therefore, there isn't a way to restrict your app to only devices supporting that feature.

Comment: hmm would requiring opengles-3 almost limit it to iphone 6 or better? (smaller subset than all phones, still not 6s or better)

Comment: @ina Unfortunately, no. OpenGL-ES 3 is available back to the iPhone 5S. Just curious, what are you doing that requires force touch to be available?

Comment: it's interesting that plist also does not have a require apple pay option either... i guess i could have the app manually display a "Not for you dead screen" by doing device check